# Windows 10 start menu does not close after starting a certain kind of apps

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

I have the Windows 10 start menu not closing after clicking on an certain kind of app to start:

**start menu closes after I start 'Windows terminal' (from Microsoft store), 'Microsoft store' and document shortcuts, but not with other apps. I also remarked that started apps at appearing in the background, behind existing apps.**

Right click with the Windows key, however do work: I start the app with win key down, when I release the win key, the start menu closes.

I tried:

```
sfc /scannow
dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

and re-register the start menu with

```
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost | Foreach`
    {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)AppXManifest.xml"}`
```

I installed and removed ExplorerPatcher 22621.2506.60.1, it was not helpful to remove the problem.

In `HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop` I have `ForegroundFlashCount` at 7, and `ForegroundLockTimeout` at 200000 (default).

I reinstalled Windows (keeping app and user data): no resolution.

I created a new local account, the problem of "start menu not closing at starting non-store apps" was gone.

From this, I understand that it's a user configuration problem, not a Windows problem.

I managed to reproduce the problem from another account, by importing the registry

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\Cache\DefaultAccount
```

The content is here: https://github.com/mprevot/SO/blob/main/StartLayout.reg

I use Windows 10 Enterprise 22h2 19045.3758. Until recently I had no problem (KB5032278 may be causing this).

Comment: What other windows shell applications do you have other than Explorer Patcher? I would start by uninstall Explorer Patcher to eliminate that is the cause of this behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound I added explorerpatcher just before posting, hoping it would help. I do not have it, it is not causing the problem. What do you call a shell application ? explorer patcher is not a shell script (cmd, powershell), so I am confused.

Comment: Anything that interfaces with File Explorer, in other words, any application like Explorer Patcher.

Comment: If ExplorerPatcher was installed on the computer, it might have left behind a bad patch of Windows. My advice is to do [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) to get things back to a known state.

Comment: @harrymc No, again, I had the problem BEFORE installing explorerpatcher. No, this does not seems appropriate, there must be something more fine grained (I tried a few, without success).

Comment: You already did the more fine grained ... Repair Install is the same as a Windows upgrade, keeping settings and apps. Take the same precautions including backup.

Comment: @harrymc Don't you think there is something to understand, using x64dbg/attach to process, or some sysinternal's process explorer to discover what is wrong ? The cause of the problem must be ridiculously simple.

Comment: It would be simple if we had a handle on the problem, but this problem is uncommon. On the other hand, problems after installing ExplorerPatcher *are* common.

Comment: @harrymc It seems it is not a corrupted start menu but some wrong setting, since the symptom is not the same with every app. This also suggests that a reinstall won't solve the issue.

Comment: Repair install is only the same as a Windows upgrade - it keeps settings and apps, and you should take the same precautions for backups.

Comment: @harrymc Reinstall did not have any effect. Same symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know what has gone wrong with your Windows setup.
Even strong-arm methods, such as Repair Install, have not fixed the
problem. The remaining solutions as far as I can see are:

- **User profile corruption** : Create a new user profile and check if it
  shows the same problem. If it does not, then move your files to the
  new profile and abandon the corrupted one.
- **Complete re-installation** : Format the hard disk and install your
  applications, settings and data.
- **Abandon Microsoft's Start Menu** : Install a third-party Start menu app.
  My favorite is the free and open-source
  [Open-Shell](https://open-shell.github.io/Open-Shell-Menu/),
  but there exist other
  [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/classic-start/).

Comment: Point 1 is good, and indeed the start menu problem is not present (antoher problem however is here: I can't move tiles). Points 2 and 3 are not solutions.

Comment: Profile corruption is almost impossible to analyze, but it's good that you did the Repair Install after ExplorerPatcher. For moving the files : Could you add to your post the commands used and the errors, and let me know.

Comment: I wrote that I can't more the tiles, not the files.

Comment: If you wish to restore the Start menu, see for example [this article](https://www.top-password.com/blog/backup-and-restore-start-menu-layout-in-windows-10/).

Comment: I have the feeling your are giving random pieces of advice, or that you do not understand the problem or the piece of advice. Reseting the layer won't solve the functions of the start menu.

Comment: I don't understand: Either the new profile is working fines and the tiles can be rearranged, even manually, or it's not working and you have to use another of the above solutions.

Comment: I generally agree with @harrymc 's approach.

Comment: @harrymc Sorry, it was not clear. The first account has the "not closing start menu" problem (and only this problem), the second account has the "unmovable tiles" problem (and only this problem).

Comment: @John Do you mean that you would reset the layout to solve the "not closing start menu" and the "unmovable tiles" problem ?

Comment: I think that would work. Nothing is certain, but it is most certainly worth trying.

Comment: @John Why would it work ? I mean you are saying that "changing the data will make the function work".

Comment: User profile errors are tricky and nothing is certain there. That is why Harry also added complete re-installation .

Comment: @John This wont' solve a problem, this will replace a problem by another (huge overhead), without guarantee that there won't be another problem (cf the new admin account where I can't move tiles). So, no this is not a solution, it's rather a runaway.

Comment: So then try a complete fresh install as was proposed.

Comment: @John It seems it works, the delay to have the tile starting to move was longer than the usual with the other account. Beside this, I managed to reproduce with the new account the bug of start menu not closing, it seems it's related to something in the registry or the layout XML. That why repairing, reinstalling and resetting the layout does not solve anything.